# Where condition and subquery

Tags: sql

I have following sql select statement :-

```
SELECT A.RowNo, A.Name, A.Address   
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by Table1.ID)   
As RowNo, Table1.Name, Table1.Address From Table1) A
WHERE RowNo Between 1 And 10
```

When i will execute above statement then which one will first execute sub query or main query?

Please suggest me

thanks

Comment: `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by Table1.ID)   
As RowNo, Table1.Name, Table1.Address` Executes First. Why such a doubt?

Comment: every time Subquery execute first

Comment: @Arun P Johny why asp.net and c# tags stille there?

Answer (score 0):

The [query optimizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_optimization) decides which is the most efficient way to execute queries. It know how many rows are in the tables. I would also suggest to to at the [`Include Actual Execution Plan`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_plan) function in SQL Server Enterprise Manager and inspect the order.

Answer (score 0):

Your sub query will execute first

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by Table1.ID) As RowNo, Table1.Name, Table1.Address From Table1
```

Above query is an example of inline view, which has data from `Table1` with some additional columns and this view can be called as `A`.

So, you final query become

```
SELECT A.RowNo, A.Name, A.Address FROM A WHERE RowNo Between 1 And 10
```

where `A` has columns **`RowNo`,`Name`,`Address`**

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat misleading. You're assuming that 2 queries need to be executed. In that case the common sense tells would tell you that inner queries must get executed before the outer queries.

However, any decent query optimizer (you haven't specified which product and version you're using) should be able to deduce that this in fact a single query, and it's only the stupid limitation of the SQL language that is not allowing you to write:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by Table1.ID) As RowNo, Table1.Name, Table1.Address From Table1 WHERE RowNo Between 1 And 10
```

Feel free to express your frustration to the ANSI (sets the SQL standard). If indeed the optimizer that you use has to perform 2 separate passes, i.e. materialize the inner query into a temp table and then perform another scan of the temp table to perform filtering, go send your vendor an angry email or just get a different product. :)